# Are there separate instruments (guitar, drums) available for purchase for Xbox One?

Tags: guitar-hero-live

Can I buy a guitar or drums to play on my Xbox One without having to buy a bundle with a game, like Guitar Hero?

I can buy a Guitar Hero Live bundle for Xbox One that comes with a guitar. What if I want to buy another guitar for multiplayer? I can't seem to find separate instruments for sale.

Are there separate instruments available?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are able to buy standalone guitars for Guitar Hero Live.

[Here](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/activision-guitar-hero-live-guitar-controller/4686800.p?skuId=4686800) is the product link for Best Buy (the first link I found).

However, from [here](http://www.cheatsheet.com/technology/your-rock-band-4%E2%80%B2-and-guitar-hero-live-questions-answered.html/?a=viewall), it looks like Guitar Hero Live *only* features the guitar, unlike Rock Band (and previous iterations of Guitar Hero).

> Guitar Hero Live: No, this game is all about the guitar.

Additionally, guitars for Guitar Hero from previous games will not be compatible with Guitar Hero Live.